# If else code help in try/ except block

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
SomeDict = {'Sarah':20, 'Mark': 'hello', 'Jackie': 'bye'}
try: 
    result = ""
    theKey = raw_input("Enter some key: ")
    val = someDict[theKey]
    except keyErrorr:
        result "hello"
    else:
        result = result + "" + "done"
    print result
```

I understand the try block you can insert and code to try and see what error comes up, and the error then can be caught by the except block. I am trying to figure out the best way to insert a if / else in  the try and except block for the same key error that is present in this code.  I was thinking that i could just replace the try and except with If/else or is it possible to just add a if/else in the try and except.  Any help on how to insert a if/else into this code for key error would be greatly appreciated. So basically i want to add a if/else code into the try and except block for the same key error.

```
 SomeDict = {'Sarah':20, 'Mark': 'hello', 'Jackie': 'bye'}
    try: 
        result = "" #could i insert something like if result == "" : #for this line?
        theKey = raw_input("Enter some key: ")
        val = someDict[theKey]
        except keyErrorr:
            result "hello"
        else:
            result = result + "" + "done"
        print result
```

Comment: Your code has a syntax error. The `except` and `else` lines need to be on the same level of indentation as the `try` line.

Comment: the exception name is `KeyError` with K and one r at the end

Comment: also, `result = "hello"`

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do, but I think you need to review the fundamentals.

Comment: Limit the `try` block to only include the line where you access the dictionary

Comment: I want to insert a if else statement that would do the same operation as the try except.  The except will catch the key error

Answer (score 2):

One reasonable option is to initialize `result = None`, then test `if result is None:`.

It's better to use None than the empty string, since someday you might want a dictionary value to be the empty string, plus None is probably clearer to the casual reader of your code.

You could also just skip the try-except, and use `if theKey in someDict:`.

Answer (score 1):

you can add another except without a specification what exception it should handle.

```
try:
   # do something
except KeyError:
   # do something because of the Keyerror
except:
   # do what you need to do if the exception is not a KeyError
```

Answer (score 0):

```
someDict = {'Sarah':20, 'Mark': 'hello', 'Jackie': 'bye'}   # corrected dict name
result = ""
theKey = raw_input("Enter some key: ")
try:                    # just try the code where the error could be
    val = someDict[theKey]
except KeyError:        # corrected exception name and indent level
    result = "hello"    # corrected syntax
else:                   # corrected indent level
    result = result + "" + "done"       # why add "" ?
print result
```

does this work for you?